# Query to aggregate amount across different rate categories as applicable per usage

Tags: php, mysql, sum, multiplication, number-formatting

**Scenario**:
I need to calculate sum of amount applicable to each client based on their hourly rates and time(minutes) they offered/received services in different rate categories.

Using the following query I get the below results:

```
SELECT pc.client_id, pr.hourly_rate, (SUM(tt.time_end) - SUM(tt.time_start)) as Difference
FROM  track_time as tt, project_track as pt, project as pr, project_clients as pc, clients as cl
WHERE tt.track_id = pt.track_id
AND pt.project_id = pr.project_id
AND pr.project_id = pc.project_id
AND pc.client_id = cl.client_id 
GROUP BY hourly_rate
```

**RESULTS**

```
client_id   hourly_rate   Difference
1           50            6360
1           23            4080
1           43            5760
6           13            34680
7           60            32400
7           14            23340
```

I'm trying to figure out how to FIRST I need to convert the DIFFERENCE result to readable hours using a function, THEN multiply that converted result times it's respective hourly_rate, and then get the SUM for each client.

I tried this (below) first, which is really close, but it's not accurate.  I'm thinking it's not accurate because I need to first convert the DIFFERENCE column first.

```
SELECT SUM(Difference2) AS total
FROM (SELECT pc.client_id, pr.hourly_rate, (SUM(tt.time_end) - SUM(tt.time_start)) as Difference, ((SUM(tt.time_end) - SUM(tt.time_start)) * pr.hourly_rate) as Difference2
FROM  track_time as tt, project_track as pt, project as pr, project_clients as pc, clients as cl
WHERE tt.track_id = pt.track_id
AND pt.project_id = pr.project_id
AND pr.project_id = pc.project_id
AND pc.client_id = cl.client_id   
GROUP BY hourly_rate) AS table1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are virtually there, move the multiplication by the hourly rate to the outside query, and keep the calculation of the difference on the subquery.

Comment: You got me thinking so I ended up with this working solution:

`SELECT SUM(T) as YES FROM ( SELECT pc.client_id, pr.hourly_rate,  ROUND((( SUM(tt.time_end) - SUM(tt.time_start))/3600),2) as Difference, (ROUND((( SUM(tt.time_end) - SUM(tt.time_start))/3600),2) * hourly_rate) as T
FROM  track_time as tt, project_track as pt, project as pr, project_clients as pc, clients as cl
WHERE tt.track_id = pt.track_id
AND pt.project_id = pr.project_id
AND pr.project_id = pc.project_id
AND pc.client_id = cl.client_id
AND cl.client_id = " . $db->prep($client_id) . "    
GROUP BY hourly_rate) as table1`
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
SELECT SUM(T) as YES FROM (
SELECT pc.client_id, pr.hourly_rate, ROUND((( SUM(tt.time_end) - SUM(tt.time_start))/3600),2) as Difference, (ROUND((( SUM(tt.time_end) - SUM(tt.time_start))/3600),2) * hourly_rate) as T
FROM track_time as tt, project_track as pt, project as pr, project_clients as pc, clients as cl
WHERE tt.track_id = pt.track_id
AND pt.project_id = pr.project_id
AND pr.project_id = pc.project_id
AND pc.client_id = cl.client_id
AND cl.client_id = " . $db->prep($client_id) . " GROUP BY hourly_rate) as table1
```